# Passing arguments to oracle stored procedure through scheduler job

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g, scheduler, dbms-scheduler

I have a stored procedure which is being called from a dbms job. i.e.

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB ('Procedure_JB', FALSE);
```

A java code stored procedure, which after doing some stuff, kicks off Procedure_JB asynchronously. And then this Procedure_JB calls Procedure_PRogram and then the program would call the stored procedure.

How can i pass arguments to my stored procedure?

- The arguments which i have to pass to the job are from java.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Define your job Procedure_JB to accept arguments. Then use dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value to define the value of the arguments you want to pass into the program your job is going to run. An example (taken from https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=483135)

```
-- create a stored procedure with two arguments
create or replace procedure myproc (arg1 in varchar2, arg2 in varchar2)
is BEGIN null; END;
/

-- create a program with two arguments and define both
begin
dbms_scheduler.create_program
(
program_name=>'myprog',
program_action=>'myproc',
program_type=>'STORED_PROCEDURE',
number_of_arguments=>2, enabled=>FALSE
) ;

dbms_scheduler.DEFINE_PROGRAM_ARGUMENT(
program_name=>'myprog',
argument_position=>1,
argument_type=>'VARCHAR2',
DEFAULT_VALUE=>'13');

dbms_scheduler.DEFINE_PROGRAM_ARGUMENT(
program_name=>'myprog',
argument_position=>2,
argument_type=>'VARCHAR2');

dbms_scheduler.enable('myprog');
end;
/

-- create a job pointing to a program and set both argument values
begin
dbms_scheduler.create_job('myjob',program_name=>'myprog');
dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('myjob',1,'first arg');
dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('myjob',2,'second arg');
dbms_scheduler.enable('myjob');
end;
/
```

Comment: A nightmare might be @AlexanderMills, but that's the generic way to handle arbitrary programs with arguments other than `VARCHAR2`. If all arguments are of type `VARCHAR2`, then one could simply do what `Steve G` suggested.

Answer (score 9):

Use PLSQL_BLOCK instead:

```
begin
dbms_scheduler.create_job (
    job_name => 'myjob',
    job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action => 'BEGIN myproc(''first arg'',''second arg''); END;',
    start_date => sysdate,
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=HOURLY',
    enabled => true    
);
end;
/
```

Comment: I +rep this since it is the simpler choice,but only when the arguments are of type VARCHAR2. If the procedure expects something else (say, timestamp arguments), then this won't fly.

Comment: If you need to run a job asynchronously , then skip the SYSDATE column.

Answer (score 0):

How it could work in version 19c (may be earlier)

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
    job_name => 'TMP_JOB_'||'test_procedure_job', -- customize job name
    job_type => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
    job_action => 'PACKAGE_NAME.test_procedure',
    number_of_arguments => 2,
    start_date => NULL,
    repeat_interval => NULL,
    end_date => NULL,
    enabled => FALSE,
    auto_drop => TRUE, -- in my case onetimer object - not to store in DB schema
    comments => '');
    
    dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value(job_name => 'TMP_JOB_'||'test_procedure_job',
                      argument_position => 1,
                      argument_value => ''||'text_arg');
                     
    dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value(job_name => 'TMP_JOB_'||'test_procedure_job',
                      argument_position => 2,
                      argument_value => 100500); -- number arg
    
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable(name => 'TMP_JOB_'||'test_procedure_job');
END;
```