# Run Oracle Sched. Program Immediately

Tags: oracle11g, scheduled-tasks

I am working on Oracle 11g. I have a *sched. program* that passes arguments and executes an OS application. I need to override the values of these arguments and run the *sched. program* on call by executing some *pl/sql* script. Scheduling the execution on some time intervals does not fulfill my needs.

Would you help me please :) thank you.

Comment: I guess one way would be to refactor so that what sched program run is easily callable directly.

Comment: @user2672165 I am not that familiar with Oracle. Would you please describe how it would be done?

Comment: This post can perhaps guide you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179775/passing-arguments-to-store-procedure-through-scheduler-jb