# Oracle DBMS_SCHEDULER sysdate argument

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm using Oracle12c. I'm working with DBMS_SCHEDULER to execute a procedure every minute. I want to pass one argument to this procedure with the current datetime (SYSDATE) in each execution.

But this argument is evaluated just one time, when I create the job. Then, in every consecutive executions, the value of the argument is always the same (the create job date).

```
-- procedure signature
test_proc(v_aud_date in date);

-- scheduler_job
begin
    dbms_scheduler.create_job (
          job_name              => 'test_JOB'
        , job_type              => 'STORED_PROCEDURE'
        , job_action            => 'test_proc'
        , number_of_arguments   => 1
        , start_date            => SYSTIMESTAMP
        , repeat_interval       => 'freq=minutely; interval=1;'
    );

    dbms_scheduler.set_job_anydata_value(
          job_name          => 'test_JOB'
        , argument_position => 1
        , argument_value    => sys.anydata.convertDate(sysdate)
    );

    dbms_scheduler.enable('test_JOB');
end;
```

I want to get the current SYSDATE for every execution. I can't change the procedure. Is a black box for me.

Is it possible with DBMS_SCHEDULER?

P.S.: Probably I've made mistakes... Sorry for my English!

Comment: I guess this could help [Passing arguments to oracle stored procedure through scheduler job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179775/passing-arguments-to-oracle-stored-procedure-through-scheduler-job)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the job as a PL/SQL block, like so:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
     job_name             => 'test_JOB',
     job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
     job_action           => 'BEGIN test_proc(sysdate); END;',
     start_date           => SYSTIMESTAMP,
     repeat_interval      => 'freq=minutely; interval=1';
     enabled              =>  TRUE,
     comments             => 'Test job');
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

To pass the argument to the scheduler you can use as below:

```
, job_action            => 'test_proc(v_aud_date); END;'
```

Answer (score 0):

`sysdate` is evaluated on execution time. Script that creates job you call once so this `date` is evaluated once when created job.
If you need `sysdate` from execution not creation time just use `sysdate` inside code that you are executing not pass it via parameter. In every place of PL/SQL code you have `sysdate`so in `test_proc` add `declare curr_time date := sysdate;` and use `curr_time` in place where you would use previously passed parameter. 
You can also change procedure to have this parameter `default sysdate` and in job call without parameter at all.