# How to send a response via OUT parameter but still doing some processing?

Tags: plsql

For e.g. From middle layer it calls PLSQL procedure having both IN and OUT parameters. The PLSQL Procedure is doing complex task So I dont want the service to wait until PLSQL prcedure done its part. I want send some response like OK and do the rest of the processing. There will not be any impact on Procedure response.

Expecting some way to achieve this

Comment: What "middle layer"?

Comment: You can use the approach from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54966759/how-to-run-oracle-stored-procedures-asynchronously-and-independently-from-client